# create a program which takes 2 digits, X,Y as input and generates a 2-dimensional array

Tags: python

I need to take number of `row(x)` and `column(y)` as user input separated by comma etc. and create a 2D array out of it. 
where `array[x][y]=x*j`

This is what i am trying:

```
userInput = raw_input("Enter values for row and column number:\t").split(",")
for x in range(userInput):
    for y in range(userInput[x]):
        userInput[x][y]=x*y
        print(userInput[x][y])
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Please try to solve this problem yourself and add your effort (code) to your question. Then we can correct your approach.

Comment: You should take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i am new to python. and i tried. i am ot getting the desired result hence asking for assistance on stackoverflow

Comment: What's `j`? And why do you want to use an array for this? Why not just use a 2D list?

Comment: You create an array where position (x,y) is `x+j`, what about the rest of the array? You want it to be 0?

Comment: userInput = raw_input("Enter values for row and column number:\t").split(",")
for x in range(userInput):
    for y in range(userInput[x]):
        userInput[x][y]=x*y
        print(userInput[x][y])

Comment: this is what i am doing. assist me if i am doing anything wrong in the syntax

Comment: @shikha update your  question to include the code (don't forget to format it properly)

Comment: Why you do a nested loop? Your input is just two digits. Since you are splitting them you can access the elements doing `userInput[0]` and `userInput[1]`. However is still unclear what 2D arrays are needed here. Do you want to input all the array values using user input?

Comment: was just goin through certain python questions and found this one. and trying to get the desired result. Plus i am new on stackoverflow thus inconvenience regretted about how to state my questions properly. still getting the hang of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161193/discussion-between-sembei-norimaki-and-shikha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

When you read user input you get strings. If you want to do arithmetic with that input you have to convert it to numbers.

Your code is a bit confusing because you use `userInput` for the initial user input, but then you try to use it for the number grid you're constructing too.

You try to set `userInput[x][y]` before it exists, so that's not going to work. The usual way to work with Python lists is to add stuff to the end of them.

Here's a modified version of your code.

```
from __future__ import print_function

user_input = raw_input("Enter values for row and column number: ")
rows, cols = user_input.split(",")
rows = int(rows)
cols = int(cols)

grid = []
for x in range(rows):
    row = []
    for y in range(cols):
        row.append(x * y)
    grid.append(row)
    print(row)

print()
print(grid)
```

**demo**

```
Enter values for row and column number: 4,5
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12]

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

BTW, since you're just starting Python you ought to be learning Python 3. You can go back and learn the old-fashioned Python 2 later, if you really need to.

Comment: thank you for explaining solution and where i was getting wrong. i got the correct output. thanks a lot for you assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a nested list comprehension:

```
X, Y = raw_input("Enter values for row and column number:\t").split(",")

X = int(X)
Y = int(Y)
array = [[x*y for y in range(Y)] for x in range(x)]
```

The first line binds the values entered for rows and columns to `X` and `Y`. These are strings, so they are then converted to integers for use in `range()`. Finally the list comprehension creates the "array" represented as a list of lists.